# How to remove Data between Tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, vba

I have very large amount of data, and I have a task to create a mapping of the same. To create a mapping I want to delete data between  till  in XML. Below is the example I want to have.

```
 <SubIssue id = "1" sName = "Heading">
                <Issues>
                <Child name="Symptom/ Cause" value="How TO"></Child>
                </Issues> 
                <Questions>
                    <Question>
<![CDATA[<font color='#333333' size='3' face='Calibri'><b>Bull</b></font>
<font color='#15428B' size='2' face='Calibri'>1Data1</font>

<font color='#333333' size='3' face='Calibri'><b>Rock</b></font>
<font color='#15428B' size='2' face='Calibri'>Data2</font>
</br>]]>
                    </Question>
                </Questions>

                <SP>No</SP>
                </SubIssue>
```

So I want to delete all the data betwen `<SubIssue>` and `</SubIssue>`. It should look like this

```
<SubIssue>
</SubIssue>
```

That's It.

I can use any language like php, html or anything./ Visual basic also will do.
Please Help

Comment: You want to delete all the data between `<SubIssue>` and `</SubIssue>` ?

Comment: Is the SubIssue static or dynamic? I mean, do you have several cases or just this one?

Comment: are you using any programming language ??

Comment: SubIssue is Static...its only the head in all the data..

Comment: yeah..i was trying with php but with no efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And in PHP it will look like this ...

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$data = $dom->loadXML($yourXmlString);

$tmp = $dom->documentElement;
$childnodes = $tmp->getElementsByTagName('SubIssue')->item(0)->childNodes;

foreach ($childnodes as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild(clone $node);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

This code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#1").html("");
});
});
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mjMm7/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am new to php and xml both...I am working on something like above.

but I didn't understood in Marcel's code

```
$yourXmlString
```

where do I put my XML data? It has to be a URL and file name in `$yourXmlString` or just copy paste RAW data from my XML file?

Thanks..

Comment: You have different methods in the DomDocument object for loading an external URL or just loading an xml string. The method DomDocument::loadXML() is for loading a XML string. The method DomDocument::load() is for loading a file or a complete URL.

Comment: Hmm..Okay..But Marcel if you can give me the whole html+php code for the above function. It will be a great help for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just have a look in the php documentation for further examples for both methods. 
http://de1.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.load.php
http://de1.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.loadxml.php